# Which azure services to use to notify something has completed?

Tags: azure, event-handling

I have an Azure function processing a file uploaded by end user which could take a long time. I'd like to notify the end user when process is completed. I'm not clear whether Azure event grid topic, event hub, service bus or other services would be best for this?

I'd like the user to be able to register how they would like to get notified as well. Is there an Azure service that would accomodate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Azure Logic Apps to run your functions at a specific time and notify end users by email when finished for instance. Azure Logic Apps are used to run automated workflows that integrate your apps, data, services, and systems.

Link that could be helpful: [Create and run your own code from workflows in Azure Logic Apps by using Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions)

Comment: Are there other options beside using Logic Apps? If the consumer wants to programmtically subscribed to an event topic for example or something programatically so they can respond to when processing is done?

Comment: As you listed, there are three Azure messaging services: Event Grid, Event Hub, and Service Bus.
If you want to send/receive an event, you can use Event Grid or Event Hub. Event Grid is used for reactive programming while Event Hub is needed for telemetry and distributed data streaming.  Service Bus is used as a brokered messaging system.

Link to compare the services: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services

Comment: Thanks, that article helps. In my case I do not need to know how to subscriber will handle the event, so looks like what I need is to send an event and not a message. I'm looking further into event grid but sounds like that's what I would need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Signal R](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-overview) service by Azure. It will be useful in case you want to notify user on any real-time update from the server.

you can refer [Signal R using Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-azure-functions)  to implement it with azure function.